# Why dereferencing a string iterator yields a const char reference?

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a nonconst string,when dereferencing its string iterator,i have found debug information show it had a type of const char reference.Why this happen?

```
string str{ "Hello,world" };
for (auto it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
{
    *it = toupper(*it);
    cout << *it;
}
```

Using Visual studio 2015.

Comment: `*it` returns a `const` reference only if `it` is a `const_iterator`, which `begin()` returns only if it is called on a `const std::string`, which is not the case in your example.  So, there is no way that `*it` is a `const` reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it yielded a const char reference then the code `*it = toupper(*it);` would fail to compile, since you cannot assign to a `const`.

Perhaps the debug information is wrong, or you misinterpret the debug information.